# I added a symbolic file to GDB. Why is the address different?

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, debug-symbols

I added a symbolic file to the GDB to debug the kernel module.
However, the GDB output is different from the address I registered.

Why is the address of the cardev_write () function 0x13d?
I want to make the address of the cardev_write () function 0xffffffffffc0904119.

Module memory

```
@ubuntu:~$ sudo cat /proc/kallsyms |grep chardev
ffffffffc0904000 t chardev_release  [chardev]
ffffffffc090403a t copy_overflow.constprop.0    [chardev]
ffffffffc0904056 t chardev_read [chardev]
ffffffffc0904119 t chardev_write    [chardev]
ffffffffc090420c t chardev_init [chardev]
ffffffffc09065a0 b chardev_cdev [chardev]
ffffffffc0906608 b chardev_major    [chardev]
ffffffffc0906580 b __key.28485  [chardev]
ffffffffc0906580 b chardev_class    [chardev]
ffffffffc0904390 t chardev_exit [chardev]
ffffffffc09051d5 r .LC2 [chardev]
ffffffffc0906140 d __this_module    [chardev]
ffffffffc0906000 d chardev_fops [chardev]
ffffffffc0904390 t cleanup_module   [chardev]
ffffffffc090420c t init_module  [chardev]
ffffffffc0906480 b G_Data   [chardev]
ffffffffc04b5120 d kvm_chardev_ops  [kvm]
@ubuntu:~$
```

System info

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.18.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 09:04:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Set gdb

```
$ gdb /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.18.0-13-generic
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.2-0ubuntu1) 8.2
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.18.0-13-generic...done.
(gdb) add-symbol-file Kernel/Module/SS/chardev.ko 0xffffffffc0904000
add symbol table from file "Kernel/Module/SS/chardev.ko" at
    .text_addr = 0xffffffffc0904000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from Kernel/Module/SS/chardev.ko...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b chardev_write
Breakpoint 1 at 0x13d
(gdb)
```

Makefile

```
obj-m := chardev.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

**+Add information**

Section Headers

```
@ubuntu:~/Kernel/Module/SS$ readelf -WS chardev.ko | grep '\.text$'
@ubuntu:~/Kernel/Module/SS$ readelf -WS chardev.ko | grep '.text'
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000000000 000064 000000 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 3] .text.unlikely    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 000064 0003bb 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 4] .rela.text.unlikely RELA            0000000000000000 001278 0006a8 18   I 17   3  8
@ubuntu:~/Kernel/Module/SS$
```

Symbol info

```
@ubuntu:~/Kernel/Module/SS$ nm chardev.ko | grep ' chardev_release$'
000000000000006d t chardev_release
@ubuntu:~/Kernel/Module/SS$
```

/proc/kallsyms

```
@ubuntu:~/Kernel/Module/SS$ sudo cat /proc/kallsyms |grep chardev
ffffffffc0587000 t device_lseek [chardev]
ffffffffc058706d t chardev_release  [chardev]
ffffffffc05870a7 t chardev_write    [chardev]
ffffffffc0587136 t chardev_read [chardev]
ffffffffc05871f0 t chardev_init [chardev]
ffffffffc0589460 b chardev_cdev [chardev]
ffffffffc05894c8 b chardev_major    [chardev]
ffffffffc0589440 b __key.28489  [chardev]
ffffffffc0589440 b chardev_class    [chardev]
ffffffffc0587348 t chardev_exit [chardev]
ffffffffc0589100 d __this_module    [chardev]
ffffffffc0589000 d chardev_fops [chardev]
ffffffffc0587348 t cleanup_module   [chardev]
ffffffffc05871f0 t init_module  [chardev]
@ubuntu:~/Kernel/Module/SS$
```

Debug

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file Kernel/Module/SS/chardev.ko 0xffffffffc058706d
add symbol table from file "Kernel/Module/SS/chardev.ko" at
    .text_addr = 0xffffffffc058706d
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from Kernel/Module/SS/chardev.ko...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) p chardev_write 
Cannot access memory at address 0x8d
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `(gdb) add-symbol-file Kernel/Module/SS/chardev.ko 0xffffffffc0904000`

This is most likely adding the module at the wrong address.

To figure out correct address, you need two numbers:

- the start of `.text` section in `chardev.ko` (use `readelf -WS chardev.ko | grep '\.text$'` to find it)
- the relocation that the kernel applied when loading `chardev.ko`. The easiest way to find this relocation is to compute the delta between `&chardev_release` from `/proc/kallsyms` -- `0xffffffffc0904000` here, and the address of the symbol in `chardev.ko` -- use `nm chardev.ko | grep ' chardev_release$'` to get it).

Add the two numbers together, and that should be the address where you want to `add-symbol-file`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I did as you told me, but I couldn't solve the problem.
I wrote additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The linux kernel using unlikely/likely macro to optimize the compilation, generate .text and .text.unlikely section correspondly.

The probe function is compiled into .text.unlikely, and add-symbol-file only add .text section to the address you assigned, which is not contains the probe function.

To solve the problem, add .text.unlikely manualy in the gdb shell:

`add-symbol-file Kernel/Module/SS/chardev.ko 0xffffffffc058706d -s .text.unlikely 0xffffffffc05870d2`

> 0xffffffffc05870d2 = 0xffffffffc058706d + 0x64